# How to extract group members detail output in csv file from names.nsf in lotus domino

Tags: lotusscript

I need help in exracting group members details in csv file from names.nsf in lotus domino.
I have script downloaded from IBM site to extract the same, but the details are coming in message box, i need details in text or csv file so that it can be used further.
Please help

Script

```html
Sub Initialize
 Dim session As New NotesSession
 Dim dbCurrent As NotesDatabase
 Dim gman As New NotesGroupManager(True)
 
 Set dbCurrent = session.CurrentDatabase
 Call gman.LoadAddressBook(dbCurrent)
 
 ' Get information about all groups
 Call gman.LoadAllGroups ' what happens if you comment out this line?
 
 Dim groupList As Variant
 groupList = gman.CachedGroups
 
 Dim intCount As Integer
 Dim strGroupDesc As String
 Dim varSubgroups As Variant
 Dim varTemp As Variant
 Dim boolHasSubgroups As Boolean
 
 Forall group In groupList
  intCount = intCount + 1
  boolHasSubgroups  = False
  strGroupDesc = "List tag: " & Listtag(group) & {
Name: } & group.Name & {
Description: } & group.Description & {
Owner: } & atImplode(group.Owner, ", ") & {

Members: }
  varTemp = group.Members
  Forall x In varTemp
   ' here's how to test whether a name is the name of a group. This is not as efficient as
   ' checking the Subgroups property, but I wanted to list the members in order (also,
   ' this will work even if we aren't in recursive mode).
   If gman.getGroup(x) Is Nothing Then
    ' the current member is not a group.
    strGroupDesc  = strGroupDesc  & x & ", "
   Else
    ' emphasize a group name by putting "<<< >>>" arround it.
    strGroupDesc  = strGroupDesc  & "<<<" & x & ">>>, "
    boolHasSubgroups = True
   End If
  End Forall
  
  If boolHasSubgroups Then
   strGroupDesc = Left$(strGroupDesc, Len(strGroupDesc) -2) & {

AllMembers: } & atImplode(group.AllMembers, ", ")
  End If
  Msgbox Left$(strGroupDesc, Len(strGroupDesc) -2)
 End Forall
 
 If intCount = 0 Then
  Msgbox "No groups were found."
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you studied how this code works, looked up how to write files in LotusScript, and tried to modify the code yourself to make it write the data to a file instead of building up a string and displaying it in a msgbox?

Comment: i have studied the code and have got little idea how it is working, but i dont how to write lotus script, otherwise i would have modified by myself, also i have google for various things to understand but i am not getting things, hence asked over here, if you can share any link it will also be helpful

Comment: Start here: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_CHAPTER_4_FILE_HANDLING.html

Answer (score 0):

Open a textfile using the [Open Statement](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_OPEN_STATEMENT.html), then loop trough your data and append each line to the txtfile using the [Print # Statement](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_PRINT_LB_STATEMENT.html)

Open also creates the file if it is not there.

PS: Notes uses numbers to identify the file, see Function Freefile for details